# Phaser - Clean loadState and bootState cache DOM

Tags: jquery, image, caching, phaser-framework

I have a game make with [Phaser.js](http://phaser.io). I would like to clean all `loadState` and `bootState` cache DOM, for remove image link.

I use actually `Phaser.Cache` for remove all cache in `Game` DOM, it work but the `loadState` and `bootState` cache still there.

**When i use Phaser.Cache**

```
game.cache = new Phaser.Cache(game);
game.load.reset();
game.load.removeAll();
```

**The `Game` cache result is cleaned**

> image         Object { __default={...},  __missing={...}}
>   __default         Object { key="__default",  data=img,  base={...},  plus...}
>   __missing         Object { key="__missing",  data=img,  base={...},  plus...}

**But the `loadState`and `bootState` cache is still there**

> image         Object { __default={...},  __missing={...}, 
>   background2={...},  plus...}
>   __default         Object { key="__default",  data=img,  base={...},  plus...}
>   __missing         Object { key="__missing",  data=img,  base={...},  plus...} background      Object { key="background", 
>   url="data:image/jpeg;base64,/...q0xYqtMOKrDFiqz0sVf/9k=",  data=img, 
>   plus...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to clear each state

```
game.state.clearCurrentState();
```

The phaser doc says :

> This method clears the current State, calling its shutdown callback.
>   The process also removes any active tweens, resets the camera, resets
>   input, clears physics, removes timers and if set clears the world and
>   cache too.

you can also use

```
game.state.destroy(); // Removes all StateManager callback references to the State object, nulls the game reference and clears the States object
```

Comment: Thank you for your good reply. This solution clear and reset all my game object visual. I would like keep all object created and only clean the cache state. With `game.cache = new Phaser.Cache(game); game.load.reset(); game.load.removeAll();` only the cache is cleaned. Have you a way for make this?

Comment: I think you can't do this by Phaser.